# Inserting Loadable-Kernel-Module in Nexus S Reboots it

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I have downloaded the Samsung kernel from source.android.com and built it. Then first i installed CWM Recovery image and after that rooted my Nexus S (Android 4.1.1). Now i want to insert simple Loadable-Kernel-Module (LKM) into it but when i inserts my module by writing `insmod hello.ko` command on ADB shell then after 2-3 seconds device reboots automatically.

Below is my LKM code.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>


int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello android kernel...\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye android kernel...\n");
}
```

I don't know that whats the issue. It shows no error message or anything else just reboots and start running normally after reboot.

**EDIT**

I have compiled Samsung kernel with Android 2.2 and compiled my LKM using this kernel. This can be the reason ?

Comment: is here no one to help me? Come on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading kernel source for Nexus S using following command

`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/samsung.git`

folder appears empty. This is because we have to checkout git remote branch.
By writing `git branch -r' shows the following list of remote branches

`origin/HEAD -> origin/master

  origin/android-samsung-2.6.35-gingerbread

  origin/android-samsung-3.0-ics-mr1

  origin/android-samsung-3.0-jb

  origin/android-samsung-3.0-jb-mr0

  origin/master`

My error was that i selected `origin/android-samsung-3.0-ics-mr1`  branch but `origin/android-samsung-3.0-jb` branch is used for jelly beans 4.1.2. That's why me LKM was not compiling with correct kernel version and hence rebooting the device on every insert.